# IOS5 NSRegularExpression can't parse very basic expression

Tags: regex, ios5, nsregularexpression

I want to parse `items=14-35` with `regex` to `14` and `35`

I use  `/^items=([-\d,]+)$/` in PHP and want to use it in an iPhone project.
I checked Apple's documentation and similar questions here like [NSRegularExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442549/nsregularexpression) .

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
 [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/^items=([-\\d,]+)$/"
                 options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *str = @"items=14-35";
NSTextCheckingResult *match = 
  [regex firstMatchInString:str 
         options:NSMatchingAnchored 
         range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

NSLog(@"MATCH : %@",match);
```

The above code outputs `NULL` and `match.numberOfRanges = 0` without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delimiter slashes at the beginning and end aren't part of the regular expression. Remove them from the pattern string.

(Sometimes, slashes are used to delimit the regular expression from flags at the end, but Cocoa doesn't do that. Since you pass the flags explicitly, there's no need for the slashes.)

Comment: Yes, that was the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is split the string, you can also use [componentsSeparatedByString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a).

Of course, if you need to validate the input data, a regular expression may be better.

Comment: I prefer regular expression because after make this basic one work, I will use more complex expressions. Now trying to understand the NSRegularExpression basics.

Comment: Fair enough. I try to avoid them as much as possible.